# Apache Beam with Dataflow: flag 'ignore_unknown_columns' for WriteToBigQuery not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am building a streaming pipeline using Apache Beam (Python SDK version 2.37.0) and Google Dataflow to write some data I receive via Pubsub to BigQuery.

I process the data and end up with rows represented by a dictionary like this:

```
{'val1': 17.4, 'val2': 40.8, 'timestamp': 1650456507, 'NA_VAL': 'table_name'}
```

I then want to use [`WriteToBigQuery`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.37.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) to insert the values into my table.

However, my table only has the columns `val1`, `val2`, and `timestamp`. Therefore, `NA_VAL` should be ignored. From how I understand the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.37.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery), this should be possible by setting `ignore_unknown_columns=True`.

However, when running the pipeline in Dataflow, I still receive an error and no values are inserted into the table:

```
There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will not retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'NA_VAL', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'no such field: NA_VAL.'}]}]
```

I tried with a simple job configuration like this

```py
rows | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table='PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE',
            ignore_unknown_columns=True)
```

as well as with those parameters

```py
rows | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table='PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE',
            ignore_unknown_columns=True,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            method='STREAMING_INSERTS',
            insert_retry_strategy='RETRY_NEVER')
```

**Question**: Am I missing something here that is preventing the pipeline from working? Does anyone have the same issue and/or a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you have been bitten by a bug. This was reported as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-14039 and fixed by https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/16999. Version 2.38.0 will include this fix. Verification for that release just concluded today, so it should be available quite soon.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Lucky me the new version is released on the day I run into this bug. Just upgraded to 2.38.0 and now it works as intended.